# Telerik's Kendo UI Controls Rendering Issue

Tags: telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc, kendo-ui

I am having issue with rendering Telerik's Kendo UI controls.  In particular with DropDownList and DatePicker (there might be problems with other controls, but I have not used other controls yet).

I tested it on Chrome and IE and it's only happens in Chrome.

I have Windows 7 SP1, 4GB of RAM, Intel Core 2 Duo E8400 @ 3.00 GHz

This problem lasts from the day 1 when I started using KendoUI controls (about 2 months now), and yes I restarted my machine multiple times.

Here is just example of what I am getting.

[image]

Any ideas or suggestions are appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does it happen with any HTML page or only some? Might be possible removing all your CSS and use only those from KendoUI?

Comment: @EmilianoBartolome it happens with any page where I have KendoUI control and only with KendoUI controls.  I don't have any other CSS except of KendoUI specific, since I am only using KendoUI controls on all those pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug with CSS transitions in Chrome 22+ (Kendo UI uses them internally for widget animation). The artifacts left on the screen are caused by transitioning CSS transforms. This should be fixed in Chrome Canary, but until then you can add this CSS to your page (creating an invisible pseudo element which has a 3D transform, causing the whole page to be accelerated) to fix it:

```
body:after {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    visibility: hidden;
    height: 0;
    font: 0/0;
    -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

The next Kendo UI release will have this fix integrated.